# cv::warpAffine - Negative image coordinates

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image to which apply apply a transform using cv::warpAffine.

I also have a set of points, to which I apply the same transform.

Now, I want to sample pixels around the warped points. The problem is, that when I warp the image and the points, some of these points become negative (and as such, I can't simply use .at(i,j) to access them).

Is there an elegant way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: test for each point, whether it is still inside of the image, before trying to access it. If you want to shift the image, so that all points are still in the image, you can transform the points before warping and adjust the transformation (just add -floor(minX) and -floor(minY) to the transpose parameters of the transformation)

Comment: or, if you sample around the transformed points, you can invert the transformation and try to access the new samples points in the original image by invert-transforming them back..

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is warp the four corners of the image to get the max, min coordinates of your resultant warped Image and then translate it back to origin on the basis of minX,minY value.
The homograhy matrix for translation would be some thing like this 
`h_trans = [1, 0, -minX, 0, 1, -minY, 0, 0, 1]`. You can get the resultant transformation by multiplying this matrix with you original matrix.